# How can I extract century value from the daterange type as field in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range

Hello I am looking to extract the 'century' values from a daterange field in postgresql.

My field looks like this

> "[1759-01-01,1759-12-30)"

The result should be "18" for Eighteenth Century

I know you can do this for individual date fields such as:

```
SELECT EXTRACT('century' FROM "event_timestamp") AS "day of week"
FROM "events";
```

However, I have not found away to do the same with the daterange format.

Any help would be great

R

Comment: if your field has dates in it then you would be wanting allthe centuries present in each individual dates?? isnot it  .Moreover its not appropriate to store dates as the format you have specified .WHich format is it ??varchar??

Comment: Hi the format is "daterange". I already have it stored like the example I showed in my question and cannot change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
SELECT EXTRACT('century' FROM 
Substring("event_timestamp"::varchar),2,10)::Date) AS "day 
of week"
FROM "events";
```

But only for the first date not the successive ones.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/69da7/5

For both of them date its like :

```
SELECT EXTRACT('century' FROM Substring("a"::varchar,2,10)::Date) AS "day 
of week",EXTRACT('century' FROM Substring("a"::varchar,13,10)::Date) AS "day 
of week"
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: You superstar!! That's great.

Comment: @Rodrigo you yourself is one of the superstars !!Thanks for the green tick .You can also give it an upvote...